# How to fetch the previous and next rows based on a selected row?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to get the exact **T-SQL Statement** on fetching the previous and next rows of a selected row. Here's the given table below.

Table Name: **MyExTab**

```
ID      Name     Address       Age    Nationality
------  -------  -----------   -----  -----------
1160    Kate     New Jersey    28     American
1161    Kelly    Connecticut   32     American
1162    Jenny    New York      30     American
1163    Heather  New York      29     American
1164    Ashley   Pennsylvania  29     American
```

If I want to query a row using **ID=1162** which represents the row

```
ID      Name     Address       Age    Nationality
------  -------  -----------   -----  -----------
1162    Jenny    New York      30     American
```

it should only return the two rows which are the previous and next rows based on the selected row by ID like the following below.

```
ID      Name     Address       Age    Nationality
------  -------  -----------   -----  -----------
1161    Kelly    Connecticut   32     American
1163    Heather  New York      29     American
```

Please give assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1160,'Kate')
,(1161,'Kelly')
,(1162,'Jenny')
,(1163,'Heather')
,(1164,'Ashley');

DECLARE @id INT=1162;
```

The query will look for the **smallest bigger** and the **biggest smaller** ID to the given parameter

```
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl AS t
WHERE ID = (SELECT MIN(x.ID) FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ID>@id)
   OR ID = (SELECT MAX(x.ID) FROM @tbl AS x WHERE x.ID<@id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte
as
(
select id,
lag(id) over (order by id) as previousrwo,
lead(id) over (order by id) as nextrow
 from @tbl
 )
 select * from cte where id=1162
```

Updated for all values:may be not so efficient

```
;with cte
as
(
select *,
lag(id) over (order by id) as pr,lead(id) over (order by id) as nr
 from @tbl
 )
select * from cte
where id  = (select pr from cte where id=1162)
or id=(select nr from cte where id=1162)
```

using sample data from shungo

Comment: Yes, that's fine with SS2012+ but returns the IDs only... You might include the `where id=1162` into the cte and use the IDs in the outer query with `OR`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way (similar to `@TheGameiswar`). If you are using **sql-server-2012+** then u can use `LAG()` and `LEAD()` to get the previous and next records.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT *,
        LAG(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID)  AS PREV_RWO,
        LEAD(ID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS NEXT_ROW
    FROM    MyExTab
)

SELECT  T.*
FROM    CTE AS  C
INNER JOIN  MyExTab AS  T   ON  T.ID = C.PREV_RWO
                            OR  T.ID = C.NEXT_ROW
WHERE   C.ID = 1162
```

Comment: this gives same row twice

Comment: typo, just modified.

Answer (score 0):

Did You tried this:-

```
declare  @id int
set @id = 1162    
select * from tableName
where id in ( @id - 1 , @id + 1)
```

Comment: Would have been my first thought, but this does not allow for missing or deleted ID's

Comment: that is right, so @Shnugo ;s answer is more accurate. (voting up for it), thanks guys.